# How to take group using aggregrate in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, grouping, aggregate, aggregate-functions

I am trying to group my some of elements from this BSON data

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e25926fb081b8b5b0240"),
    "Total Detections in Frame" : "2",
    "StoreName" : "BH",
    "FPS" : "0.033",
    "Video Duration" : "3599",
    "ToTime" : "13",
    "Date" : "16-12-2018",
    "FromTime" : "12",
    "Frame Number" : "97"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e29326fb081bc5339277"),
    "Total Detections in Frame" : "2",
    "StoreName" : "BH",
    "FPS" : "0.033",
    "Video Duration" : "3599",
    "ToTime" : "13",
    "Date" : "16-12-2018",
    "FromTime" : "12",
    "Frame Number" : "97"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e29326fb081bc5339278"),
    "Total Detections in Frame" : "4",
    "StoreName" : "ME",
    "FPS" : "0.033",
    "Video Duration" : "3599",
    "ToTime" : "15",
    "Date" : "16-12-2018",
    "FromTime" : "14",
    "Frame Number" : "6"
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c18e29326fb081bc5339279"),
    "Total Detections in Frame" : "2",
    "StoreName" : "ME",
    "FPS" : "0.033",
    "Video Duration" : "3599",
    "ToTime" : "11",
    "Date" : "16-12-2018",
    "FromTime" : "10",
    "Frame Number" : "54"
}
```

Now I want sum of  **Total Detections in Frame** according to **StoreName**

I am trying this

> **{ db.generico_new.aggregate([{"$group" : {_id:"$StoreName", count:{$sum:1}}} ])**

and its results is

```
{ "_id" : "GH", "count" : 1209 }
{ "_id" : "MW", "count" : 1203 }
{ "_id" : "ME", "count" : 1443 }
{ "_id" : "BH", "count" : 1460 }
```

This giving the whole count of documents present by an respective storeName key , now how can i get result something like this

```
{ "_id" : "GH", "Total Detections in Frame" : Some Number }
{ "_id" : "MW", "Total Detections in Frame" : Some Number }
{ "_id" : "ME", "Total Detections in Frame" : Some Number }
{ "_id" : "BH", "Total Detections in Frame" : Some Number }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$StoreName",
      "Total Detections in Frame": {
        $sum: {
          $toInt: "$Total Detections in Frame"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it is giving this error  "assert: command failed: {
 "ok" : 0,
 "errmsg" : "Unrecognized expression '$toInt'",
 "code" : 168,
 "codeName" : "InvalidPipelineOperator"
} : aggregate failed
_getErrorWithCode@src/mongo/shell/utils.js:25:13
"

Comment: $toInt was added in Mongo 4.0 along with $convert that's why you are getting this error.